# Countdown after clicking a button that goes from 10 to 0 setting text on a label C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, countdown

My problem is very simple but I can't figure it out, so I need your help.

The problem is that I have a button and a label in a form, I simply want to click the button and see the label countdown from 10 to 0 and after that happens the form closes, that simple, can someone help me with this?

BTW, my real app is a form that shows video in real time from my webcam and the idea is to click the button, see the count down and when it finishes the appp saves the current frame as an image.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Have you looked into System.Timers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using WindowsFormsApplication u can do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = false; // Wait for start
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // Second
        i = 10; // Set CountDown Maximum
        label1.Text = "CountDown: " + i; // Show
        button1.Text = "Start";
    }

    public int i;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Switch Timer On/Off
        if (timer1.Enabled == true)
        { timer1.Enabled = false; button1.Text = "Start"; }
        else if (timer1.Enabled == false)
        { timer1.Enabled = true; button1.Text = "Stop"; }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            i = i - 1;
            label1.Text = "CountDown: " + i;
        }
        else 
        { timer1.Enabled = false; button1.Text = "Start"; }
    }
}
```

You only need a label, a button and a timer.

Comment: i also added some more graphic to it check it out.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you probably just need three things:

- A counter in your class as an instance variable
- A timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or a `DispatcherTimer` depending on what UI framework you're using)
- A method handling the timer's `Tick` even which decrements the counter, updates the UI, and stops the timer + takes a snapshot if the counter reaches 0

You can do all of this without any other threads.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I dont really know how to manage threads in c# (I used java before and i had problems understanding it) so if you could please point me to a code or something I will really appreciate it, and thanks for the fast response!

Comment: I'm using visual studio 11 and the default form components (label, button and picturebox).

Comment: @JonSkeet sometimes simple solutions more understandable for starters but i liked the ideas u mentioned here.. +1

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: Well the code you gave is basically the same as the solution I proposed... although I wouldn't use a public field, nor would I call it `i`.

Comment: @JonSkeet i understand but quick solution is needed and i tried to give a quick solution so i agree with that "public field" i didnt even think on privacy.. also what i tried to say i gave +1 cause u mentioned "a timer depending on UI framework" + updating it. in my code as you said i basicly did the same but it could be better looking.

Answer (score 1):

use this code. put one timer,label and button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }
    private static int i = 10;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "10";
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = (i--).ToString();
        if (i < 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this one worked too! i wish i could accept 2 answers, thank you so much!